# Reverse lookup: decimal to irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, irrational-numbers, integers

Is there an online resource that lists irrationals close to given a decimal? For example, if $x=0.3740049$, a candidate solution would be $x_c = \left ( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right ) ^2 /7$.

This would be something akin to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences), which is a reverse lookup for integer sequences and various properties about them. While there are an infinite number of irrationals over any fixed range, a list of "simple" (operation depth, low coefficients, etc...) would be very useful.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.3740049) does a pretty good job

Comment: Google Plouffe's symbolic inverter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [inverse symbolic calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced), which I think was originally coined Plouffe's inverter. It does exactly what you want. If you enter your decimals there, it will give your candidate solution as one match, other close matches for instance being $(16+9^{2/3} \cdot 11^{2/3}) / 100 \approx 0.37400477$.

Comment: Simon Plouffe was one of the major contributors to the ISC.  "Plouffe's inverter" accessed his database and was at one time at http://pi.lacim.uqam.ca/.  However, it has not been available there for some years: there is just a pointer to the ISC at  http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a system like OEIS, but as vrugtehagel said, WolframAlpha is pretty good. Also, if you know it's algebraic, it might be feasible to search for a minimal polynomial with some computer algebra system.

Comment: Well there is - Plouffe's inverter does just that.